# cannot call python3 on solaris 11

Tags: python, compilation, solaris

I am working on compiling Python package on Solaris 11.
I compiled Python 3.3.2 from source but when I call for Python3 in the terminal it says that the package is not found.
I used wget and ./configure, make, and altinstall for compiling.

I ls the /opt directory where I installed it and the Python 3.3.2 is there.
I have search the answer but could not find anything relevant.
thank you for your help.

I was not correct with my output,
here is what I type and the output I get

root@T2000-1:opt#Python3

bash: Python3: command not found

when I type

cd Python-3.3.2

I can get into Python directory and ls all the files there are.

While compiling, it didn't give me any errors.
I installed the same packages in Debian 7.1 - no problem.
I need to compile from source scipy, numpy, and matplotlib which would work with Python3.

In some of the comments on this very website I read that before you compile python X.X you need to install build-dep Python3 using apt-get, but in Solaris apt-get does not work.

I am kind of stuck and don't know what I need to do.

Comment: Did you ensure that python is in your PATH? You may check for a bin directory where you installed Python, and look there.

Comment: Thank you BenDundee, I fixed the problem adding python3 to the PATH and it worked.